# I have an iMac 11,2 and successfully installed the Mojave Patch

Tags: mojave, sip

However, I for some reason, after the installation ... my SIP is disabled.  I have been trying over and over again to put my computer into Recovery mode, but I keep getting the Prohibitory Symbol ... any suggestions of what I can do to reengage my SIP?

Comment: Wait, isn't the Prohibitory Symbol indicating the SIP is **enabled**? Have you perhaps installed any unsigned kext (i.e. drivers) before the update? That would explain why your machine doesn't boot. SIP is *on* and thus prevents the boot due to the conflicting kext. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Boot the system in internet recovery mode to enable SIP. You can do that by holding down Option-Command-R while powering on the iMac. After booting, follow instructions similar to ordinary recovery mode to enable SIP. I.e. open a Terminal and execute:

```
csrutil enable
```

If you haven't got internet recovery on the iMac, you will need to install the updated firmware software that is available for your model first.